# What are the differences between node.js and node?

Tags: node.js, apt-get, apt, linux-mint

I've installed node.js in my machine (linux mint 15), when I run `node example.js`, it says:

```
The program 'node' can be found in the following packages:
 * node
 * nodejs-legacy
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

So what are the differences between node and nodejs? I had both node.js and node installed previously, but when I run `node example.js`, the web server doesn't start at all. So I deleted node and kept node.js.

Comment: Related post - [What is the difference between node.js runtime and npm package manager options while installing node.JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41675848/465053)

Answer (score 160, accepted):

The package node is not related to node.js.

`nodejs` is what you want, however it is arguably better to have the command be called node for compatibility with scripts that use `#!/usr/bin/env node`.

You can either just create a symlink in your path:

```
sudo ln -s `which nodejs` /usr/local/bin/node
```

Or you could [install nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#install-script) and then use it to install the latest version of node.js:

```
nvm install stable
```

I prefer the nvm method, as it allows you to `sudo apt-get remove nodejs`, and then manage which version of node you're using yourself. You can also have multiple versions of node.js installed and use `nvm use <version>` to easily switch between them.

I also like to add a line to the bottom my `.bashrc` like: `nvm use stable > /dev/null`. That will automatically use the latest version you have installed.

To update your node version to the latest stable: `nvm install stable`. Every time you do this you will need to install any npm packages that you had installed globally if you want to continue using them.

To switch to an old version just run `nvm use <version>`, or, if you don't have the old version installed already: `nvm install <version>`.

Comment: actually, the `nodejs-legacy` package just contains the symlink (see also https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2012/07/msg00002.html).

Comment: Very helpful and handy is **nvm** package.

Comment: In JS world, people keep calling node; in that case does it refer to node.js ?

Comment: @vikramvi Yes, when you here people talking about node they are probably refering to node.js; either that or DOM nodes in a browser

Comment: The decision to name node and nodejs so similarly has to be the dumbest naming decision in computer history. One or both should be renamed.

Answer (score 40):

This answer is just to tell you the difference between `node` and `nodejs` packages on Debian OS.

#### `node`

- Amateur Packet Radio Node program.
- Package details link: https://packages.debian.org/source/wheezy/node

#### `nodejs`

- Node.js is a platform built on Chrome's JavaScript runtime for easily building fast, scalable network applications. Node.js uses an event-driven, non-blocking `I/O` model that makes it lightweight and efficient, perfect for data-intensive real-time applications that run across distributed devices.
- Package details link:

  - https://packages.debian.org/source/sid/nodejs

Comment: The answer that explains the _actual_ difference between `node` and `nodejs`.

Comment: How will I understand the difference between the two in layman's language?

Comment: @steady_daddy The two packages are unrelated to each other, so the simple answer is that the two are unrelated. nodejs is a modern javascript-oriented server framework typically used to provide various services and realtime applications, while node is an older framework for transmitting data packets over amateur radio. Most installations symlink the shell command "node" to the binary "nodejs" and this is usually safe to do since hardly anyone using nodejs will encounter conflicts with "node".

Comment: man node
and 
man nodejs
Yield the same exact manual pages on my WSL Debian
Hmm .....
No mention of amateur radio.
They both talk about node.js.

Answer (score 5):

**There is a simple answer.**

1. **Node.JS** is the **script/code**
2. **Node** compiles and runs the Node.JS