# Nodejs: Unexpected token * when using robe

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a nodejs app in which I am trying to use the node module called robe. Here is the error I am getting when I start the app:

```
 function* promiseToGenerator(promise) {
         ^
 Error loading module node_modules/koa
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
```

I have had trouble with the : function*  notation elsewhere as well. I am running this on node version 0.10.25.

Comment: Node 0.10 definitely doesn't support async functions. Try using a recent version of node (4.x or better) or running your code through babel first.

Comment: @ssube: This is a generator, not an async function. But it's also not supported.

Comment: @ssube Do you mean generators?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a newer version `node.js`.

Generator support was first added in `v0.11.0`, but then you needed the `--harmony` flag to use them. In version `4.0.0` they became enabled by default.

If you don't have a specific reason why you are version locked to 0.10.25, I recommend [installing nvm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20058007/772035) and then using `nvm install stable` to switch to the latest stable: version 5.4.0 .