# Tried installing nodejs latest version in windows but getting error

Tags: node.js, angular

I am trying to install nodejs latest version, in windows machine. I tried following the link [Install nodejs 4.2.0 or above version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38641977/install-nodejs-4-2-0-or-above-version) but I am getting this error

```
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: n@2.1.7
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    !win32
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
```

My current version of nodejs is v0.12.7 and npm 3.8.5 I want latest version of nodejs for angular2 setup. https://github.com/preboot/angular-webpack required nodejs Node (v6.x.x+) and NPM (3.x.x+)

Note: I don't have admin access for the system. Can someone help me with this.

Comment: You are trying to install 64 bit version on 32 bit machine

Comment: @LaxmikantDange no it's not true. Valid Arch says that ```any``` architecture supposed to be supported. The problem is that the package is not for Windows ```Valid OS: !win32```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [updating node.js in windows 7 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24822612/updating-node-js-in-windows-7-64-bit)