# How to install a project's dependencies using nvm?

Tags: npm, nvm

I'm working with `nvm` to run version `14.17.0` of node:

```
nvm current
v14.17.0
```

I'm inside the folder of a project with `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files.

I need to install the project's dependencies so I try to run `nvm install`, but I soon realize that that command is actually for `Download and install a <version>, [-s] from source`.

My question is: how do I install the project's dependencies defined in `package.json` when using nvm?

Reading the nvm help didn't clarify my question and when I google this, I only find results about how to install nvm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nvm` is for managing your node version; you want `npm install`.

Frankenstein was the guy who did the mad science; you want "Frankenstein's monster".

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Connor Low. One more question if you don't mind. When I run `nvm current`, I get `v14.17.0`, but if I then run `npm  -v`, it returns `6.14.13`. Is this normal?

Comment: Yes, but `node -v` should match. npm is a package manager for node, similar to yarn. node is the actual server and what nvm is for. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41675848/what-is-the-difference-between-node-js-runtime-and-npm-package-manager-options-w/41676076), particularly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46904463/6789816).

Comment: It does match. Thank you!