# what in deference between node and node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, npm, nvm

I installed nodejs as per this documentation 
https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

then I checked i current version of Node js

:~/Downloads$ nodejs -v

v4.2.6

Still Older version of Nodejs

then I tried to install node via nvm
as per this documentation https://askubuntu.com/questions/849270/how-can-i-install-a-tar-xz-file-from-nodejs-org

I got newest version of Node 
:~/Downloads$ node -v
v7.9.0

But When I checked version of nodejs , got still old version of nodejs.
I just confused about difference bewtween nodejs and node .

thanks in advance if any one help me to install latest version of Nodejs via ppa or by tar.xz file, I already tried each solution.

Answer (score 0):

Answers is [what are the differences between node.js and node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057790/what-are-the-differences-between-node-js-and-node)