# what is the difference between node and nodejs

Tags: node.js, nvm

After installing node via npm , using 'nvm ls' gives the version which i have installed like v8.9.4 and also node -v also shows the version. But at the same time, when checking for 'nodejs --version' tells me to install node js as 'sudo apt-get install nodejs'.

Comment: Check this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/794822/node-vs-nodejs-on-ubuntu-package-manager

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between node.js and node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057790/what-are-the-differences-between-node-js-and-node)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Via npm or nvm Node.js is called node but if you install via apt-get you need to use the package name nodejs because via apt-get node is a package name take by a completely different application that happens to also be called node.

[what are the differences between node.js and node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057790/what-are-the-differences-between-node-js-and-node)

Comment: Right now I have installed both via NVM and via 'sudo apt-get install nodejs'

Comment: Will their be any issue in future?

Comment: I would remove one. Its easier to track your version when you know which one is being ran because theres only one. The issue I run into when I have multiple versions of node is when something tries calling node and uses the wrong one so for me I only use one.